# Microdata schema parser

Tags: c#, html-parsing, microdata

I want to parse the [microdata schema](http://schema.org/) from the html content programmatically (like the way [Google Structured Data Test Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) doing)

For example given html containing the [JobPosting](https://schema.org/JobPosting) and [Website](http://schema.org/WebSite) schema, the tool will detect and return 2 objects `JobPosting` and `Website` with related properties information.

What is the best approach for this? Should I create `XSD` schema to validate the Html content or just doing normal Html processing with `XPath`? Is there any good library to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a library for accomplishing this task. The library is based on `HtmlAgilityPack` library. The code has been placed on Github: https://github.com/minhnguyenlinknode/MicroSchemaParser

Usage:

```
var microSchemaParser = new MicroSchemaParser(yourHtmlString);

// Detect all supported schemas
List<ISchema> allSupportedSchemas = microSchemaParser.Parse();

// Find a specific schema
var schema = microSchemaParser.Find<ItemListSchema>();

// Check the schema validation
var validateResult = itemListSchema.Validate();
```